# mySQL 5.7 - inventory control

Tags: mysql

Trying to figure out the way to control inventory. I mean I have created very simple DB for the rental shop and have payment table and game table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE game_tbl (
game_id INT (100) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
game_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
game_publisher VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
game_console VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
game_qty INT (10) NOT NULL,
game_avail INT (10)AS (game_qty- game_rented),
game_rented INT (10),
game_year SMALLINT );
```

and the payment table

```
CREATE TABLE payment_tbl(
payment_id INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
payment_amount decimal (5,2) not null,
payment_date DATE not null,
normal decimal (5,2) not null,
penalty decimal (5,2) not null,
refund decimal (5,2) not null,
outstanding decimal (5,2) );
```

Both are not connected but I really want to add some control. So if the game is paid in payment_tbl the game_avail in game_tbl goes -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two more table I guess...
One to store user information
**User**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Second table **purchase_detail** to map user,game and payment information.

```
CREATE TABLE `purchase_detail` ( `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,`payment_id` int(10) NOT NULL ,`game_id` int(100) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now all the three tables are mapped using table purchase_detail

Comment: Have these two tables:create table transaction_tbl (
transaction_id INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
rental_date DATE not null,
return_date DATE not null,
game_idFK INT (100) not null,
customer_idFK INT (10) not null,
payment_idFK INT (100) not null,
total_amount DECIMAL (5,2));
alter table transaction_tbl add constraint foreign key (game_idFK) references game_tbl (game_id);
alter table transaction_tbl add constraint foreign key (customer_idFK) references customer_tbl (customer_id);
alter table transaction_tbl add constraint foreign key (payment_idFK) references payment_tbl (payment_id);

Comment: @Kalenji Please mark the answer as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved. In this way it will help others looking for similar problem

Comment: and the customer table: CREATE TABLE customer_tbl (
customer_id INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
first_name VARCHAR (20) not null, 
second_name VARCHAR (20) not null, 
customer_address VARCHAR (40) not null, 
customer_city VARCHAR (20) not null, 
member_since DATE not null);
alter table customer_tbl add Store_codeFK VARCHAR (10);
alter table customer_tbl add constraint foreign key (Store_codeFK) references store_tbl (store_id);

Comment: So, just wonder what should I change to get updated records? Please also  let me know how to create a post to show SQL code not as a text?

Comment: @Kalenji For all formating there is text editor...For example for code use 4 spaces ...